# Xcode 7 not showing selected images on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard

since I updated Xcode to the last version (7.0), when I set some image on an UIImageView inside a Storyboard I can't see that image.

All images appear like the example below.

[image]

**Update**

Image on xcassets

[image]

Setting image on storyboard

[image]

Is this happening to you also?

Comment: Does the application run fine otherwise?

Comment: did it work previously ? Make sure you use correct images with extensions, and make sure you have all the images inside your project

Comment: @ShamasS yes, it runs fine!

Comment: @Mr.T yes, it worked previously.. I'll update with more images from *.xcassets and setting image on Storyboard

Comment: Do you solved your problem? I have some problem, when i run the application all works, but in storyboard nothing show up.

Comment: Not yet @GabyFitcal . Are you developing for iPad only?

Comment: no. I find the problem. For me my images was named like this: "icon_videoCall@3x.png"  if i enter just "icon_videoCall.png" without @3x is working. Hope it helps

Comment: thats because your asset contains image only for iPad and you might selected Any-Any size class in the storyboard. If you change the devices for that particular asset to universal, it will show in the storyboard